# output of api callback to show data of the first object

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am performing an api call back in a loop to get the latest status of a value.. The api call and loop is working but its not showing me the data of the first object returned.. instead it is showing me the data of the last object. The reason for the loop is because there could be multiple objects returned but i want the output to go through them in order from object 0 then object 1 and so on..

Here is a screenshot from firebug showing you two objects with there respective data points. As you can see object 0 is shown first then object 1.

[image]

Here is my code to output the data on the page. This code is within a if statement where status = "RESULT" - you can't tell from the below code but both of these objects match that criteria

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.endpoints.length; i++) {
  var endpoint = response.endpoints[i];
  //console.log(endpoint);
  $pending0.html("<br><b>Server Name: </b>" + endpoint.serverName + "<br><b>Status: </b>" + endpoint.statusMessage + "<br><b>Progress: </b>" + endpoint.statusDetailsMessage);
```

My issue with the above code is with the order of the output. It shows data for the second object where as I need it to give me the output for the first object.

-- UPDATE --

seems to be working per Barmer's suggestion to add an IF within the loop

```
    for (var i = 0; i < response.endpoints.length; i++) {
  var endpoint = response.endpoints[i];
  if (endpoint.statusMessage == "In progress") {
  //console.log(endpoint);
  $pending0.html("<br><b>Server Name: </b>" + endpoint.serverName + "<br><b>Status: </b>" + endpoint.statusMessage + "<br><b>Progress: </b>" + endpoint.statusDetailsMessage);
 }
}
```

Comment: You're replacing the HTML each time through the loop, not concatenating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the status in the loop. Since you only want to show the first endpoint that's in progress, you should break out of the loop when you find it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.endpoints.length; i++) {
    var endpoint = response.endpoints[i];
    if (endpoint.statusMessage == "In progress") {
    //console.log(endpoint);
        $pending0.html("<br><b>Server Name: </b>" + endpoint.serverName + "<br><b>Status: </b>" + endpoint.statusMessage + "<br><b>Progress: </b>" + endpoint.statusDetailsMessage);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: .append() works but then it will show all the obejcts in the output. The reason for using .html() is because i want it to show data for only one object at a time and not all the objects at once.. Anyway to only show one object which is the first object returned?

Comment: If you don't want to show all the objects, don't use a loop. Just use `response.endpoints[0]`.

Comment: mmm the issue with that is i don't know how many endpoints there are.. lets say there are 20 of them.. then i would have to specify 20 different if statements? i was hoping for a more elegant way to cycle through each one.

Comment: I don't understand. What `if` statements are you talking about?

Comment: the number of endpoints[] are unknown, are you suggesting i specify each endpoint manually i.e. response.endpoint[0], response.endpoint[1] etc.. is there a more dynamic approach to cycle through all endpoint[number] without using a loop?

Comment: If it helps, it should display the data for object that has `statusMessage="In progress"`..

Comment: You can use the loop, and put an `if` statement INSIDE the loop, so you only display the ones that have that status.

Comment: thx Barmar, i think thats the right path forward. I was trying to do that but i am not good at it.. can you help with a sample code for the if statement inside the loop?

Comment: Barmer, i think its working now per your advice of adding `if` within loop.. please review my post with the working code if you want to make any additional comments